# Are questions about software/hardware primarily related to the Internet of Things on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I recently [asked a question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/288/whats-the-purpose-of-a-gadget-snap-in-ubuntu-core) about a technical feature of Ubuntu Core (and specifically its package manager, Snappy). Some users voted to close this, so I think we should start a bigger discussion about whether these questions are fundamentally on/off-topic to help define the scope of the site.

A good point of reference in my opinion is Stack Overflow. Their [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) specifically allows questions related to:

> software tools commonly used by programmers

Should we consider a similar policy for this site, where questions about tools **commonly used for IoT** would be on-topic? Would this make the scope too broad or would excluding these make the site too narrow in its focus?

Comment: It's important to note that the Stackoverflow "software tools commonly used by programmers" does not refer to tools used by all users when the asker happens to *be* a programmer, it refers to tools specifically or customarily intended to aid programmers - ie, compilers, IDE's, etc.  It's specifically carving out an exception for *development tools* to the general policy that *using* a program (vs developing one) is off-topic there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Software and hardware tools used for IoT should be on-topic here as long as the particular use case is directly related to IoT.

There will be an overlap with other branches of SE these tools will often be used for other non-IoT applications as well. This overlap is unavoidable and a redirection to other sites may be prudent if the question could be answered in a more general sense that exceeds the realms of IoT.

Comment: The consensus seems to be that they are on-topic, so I'll go ahead and accept this answer. If anyone opposes this, feel free to post a different answer!